# ASP.NET Printing css without print dialog and modal confirmation for successful print

Tags: asp.net, html, css, printing

This might have to be broken down a bit but what i want to do:

I have:
- A List of (sort of) greeting cards.
Each will be printed to a particular size (A4 folded down the longer edge)

I want to:
Generate a list of these cards in HTML with css that puts the tags in their place
which would be rotated 90°.

Ideally i'd want to print the list of cards without ever seeing their HTML.
And without print dialog, but would want a modal confirmation dialog after printing where user input confirms they printed correctly.

So my questions are:

1. Assuming divs for each card, do i just to rotate in the css and then add pagebreaks after each card to define a new page for printing? 
   I'm really having trouble with the css, do you recommend any good resources for this?
2. Do I need to specify page size or if the particular size paper is in the printer will the printer print proportionally?
3. How can I print without browser's print dialog **This is answered**
4. How can I catch when the printing job is finished?
5. Would I be better off with using some PDF library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   3. How can I print without browser's print dialog.
> ```

This is not possible. Any browser shouldn't allow this. All you can do is to open print dialog from Javascript but user has to confirm.

Of course you can generate PDF but this requires user to print this PDF manully (clicking print button).

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.
So the only way for me to print the batch would be to generate a single html document with pagebreaks and manually print that?

Can i still throw up a modal dialog for user acceptance of print or is it all handled by the browser?

Comment: @fogedi - Even when you have single HTML with all cards, user still has to confirm printing. Of course single HTML with pagebreaks via CSS is better than multiple HTMLs because multiple HTML = multiple print dialogs and single HTML = single dialog. PDF is another story. You can split pages as you wish in PDF and give user a single PDF which will require single "print" action from user to print all cards. But maybe user first need to open PDF. So you may have two actions required from user. This depends on the browser (Chrome is best here) and the way Acrobat or other PDF viewer is installed.

Comment: @fogedi - By "user acceptance of print" you mean question like "Were the cards printed correctly?" No, this is never handled by browser or PDF viewer. (The only exception I can find of is installing printer in Windows and printing test page.) You have to implement this question yourself.

Comment: What I ended up doing was: to generate the html with pagebreaks from a list of id's and then have jquery handle the printing with iframe.
So JQuery opens the print confirmation window, shouldn't i be able to catch when the printing is done using the same jquery function?